# Android Java - Runnable confusion

Tags: java, android, runnable

I'm learning about Runnable right now and am a little confused with a code I found and how it's running.

```
j = 0;
public Runnable test = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

        if (j <= 4) { //this is an if statement. shouldn't it run only once?
            Log.i("this is j", "j: " + j);
            handler.postDelayed(this, 2000); //delays for 2 secs before moving on
        }

        j++; //increase j. but then why does this loop back to the top?

        Log.i("this is j", "incremented j: " + j);
    }
};
```

When I run this, every 2 seconds j will log from 0 to 4. I don't understand why though, but it does exactly what I need of having a data updated every 2 seconds.

Does run() just keep... running? Which would explain why it keeps looping, kinda. But then if that was the case then even after the if statement finishes j would still be incrementing itself.

Any help in explaining this would help, thanks!

Comment: It looks like whatever handler is is rescheduling it each time

Comment: The first argument of `postDelayed()` is for a `Runnable` - it just re-executes that `Runnable` it's inside (`this`) until j is 4.

Answer (score 3):

Check out [the documentation for `Handler.postDelayed(Runnable, long)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed(java.lang.Runnable,%20long)):

> Causes the Runnable r to be added to the message queue, to be run after the specified amount of time elapses.

What `postDelayed()` does is take a `Runnable` instance and call its `run()` method after a given delay. It does *not* resume execution where you left off.

In your case, you are passing `this` which is a `Runnable` that checks `if (j <=4 ))` and if so, posts that same runnable again, thus executing the `run()` method again.

If you just want a delay after checking if `j <= 4`, you likely want [`Thread.sleep()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep(long,%20int)) which will sleep a thread for a given amount of time.

Answer (score 2):

A Runnable is just that: a block of code that can be run. The magic happens when you use Runnable's with a Handler, like you are doing here. A Handler will accept Runnable's and call their run() method on the Handler's thread. You tell a Handler to run a Runnable using Hander.post() or Handler.postDelayed(). post() runs the Runnable immediately, postDelayed() runs it after a given amount of milliseconds.

So the run() method is only run once, but this line:

```
handler.postDelayed(this, 2000);
```

tells the Handler to schedule running *this* (that is, this Runnable) after 2000 milliseconds (2 seconds).